# Run SSRS report based on temporary table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am not sure if this is possible.  I have an original data set that is approximately 1.5MM records.  I want to do a number of things to this dataset in preparation to using it in a report with parameters.  I am using SSRS and SQL Server 2008 R2.

What I was thinking of doing is creating a temp table #XYZ that would have a subset of the original 1.5MM records and would have the additional fields I need for reporting.

I can do all of that in a stored procedure.  Can I use that temp table without copying it to a table in the db.

Just so you understand, two people may want to query the data at approximately the same time and I do not want to have conflicts with dropping or updating tables.

Comment: have you tried using a SQL view?

Answer (score 1):

A temporary table is unique to a connection/session and gets dropped when the proc ends. If you run the same proc from two different windows in SSMS each connection gets its own temporary table, you won't have a problem...unless you use a global temporary table with two pound signs  ##XYZ